# Prove that $f \left (\left \langle u, Au \right \rangle \right ) \leq \left \langle u, f(A) u \right \rangle.$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, examples-counterexamples, positive-definite, self-adjoint-operators

> Let $f : [0,\infty) \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Let $\mathcal H$ be any Hilbert space and let $\mathbb H$ and $\mathbb P$ be the spaces of self-adjoint operators on $\mathcal H$ and positive operators on $\mathcal H,$ respectively. We denote by $\widetilde {f},$ the induced map from $\mathbb P$ to $\mathbb H.$
>
> Suppose $f$ is convex on $[0, \infty),$ and suppose $\mathcal H$ is a finite dimensional vector space. Suppose $A \in \mathbb P$ and $u$ is a unit vector in $\mathcal H.$ Show that
>
> $$f \left (\left \langle u, Au \right \rangle \right) \leq \left \langle u, f(A) u \right \rangle.$$
>
> Does the above remain true if $\mathcal H$ is an infinite dimensional space? Justify your answer.

This question was appeared in the final semestral examination in functional analysis which I am unable to do properly. I have proved the above inequality for finite-dimensions but for infinite-dimensions I don't have any idea. Could anyone please help me in this regard?

Thanks for investing your valuable time in reading my question.

Comment: For the finite dimensional case: I would consider a diagonalization of $A$ and then use Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @Surb I am able to prove that for finite-dimensions. But for infinite-dimensions I don't have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

The functional calculus for self-adjoint operators is known to be monotone:
If $f,g:\sigma(A) \to {\mathbb R}$ are continuous and $g \le f$ on $\sigma(A)$, then $g(A) \le f(A)$. If $f:[0, \infty) \to {\mathbb R}$ is continuous and convex and $u \in {\cal H}$ is a unit vector, then there is a
supporting affine function in $\langle u,Au \rangle$, that is a function $g:{\mathbb R} \to {\mathbb R}$,
$$
g(t)=f(\langle u,Au \rangle)+ \alpha(t-\langle u,Au \rangle)
$$
with $g(t) \le f(t)$ on $[0, \infty)$. Now $g(A) \le f(A)$, thus
$$
f(\langle u,Au \rangle)=f(\langle u,Au \rangle) \langle u,u \rangle + \alpha (\langle u,Au \rangle -\langle u,Au \rangle \langle u,u \rangle)=
\langle u,g(A)u \rangle \le \langle u,f(A)u \rangle.
$$

Comment: How do you know that such a $g$ will always exist?

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable in $t_0:=\langle u,Au\rangle$ you can use the tangent. If $f$ is not differentiable there, it is one sided differentiable (as it is convex) and you can use for $\alpha$ any slope between $f'_-(t_0)$ and $f'_+(t_0)$.

Comment: Sorry for the nitpick, but this argument does not apply to $t_0=0$ (and the subdifferential may be empty in this case, for example if $f(t)=-\sqrt t$). Otherwise I really like this argument.

Comment: $A$ is a positive operator and $u \not= 0$. Thus $t_0$ should be $> 0$. Or is $A$ only semidefinite? In that case I would consider $A + \varepsilon I$ and then $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Positive usually means positive semidefinite in this context. But yes, this approximation argument works.

Comment: I don't understand your argument as to how to construct such an affine supporting function. Also how for such a $g$ we have $g(A) \leq f(A)\ $? Actually I am a new to this subject. So I need some help in this regard. Could you please elaborate a little bit more? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $E$ be the projection valued measure corresponding to $A$ obtained from spectral theory for self-adjoint operators. Then $$A = \int_{\sigma (A)} t\ dE(t).$$

Now for any $u \in \mathcal H$ with $\|u\| = 1$ we have $$\left \langle u, Au \right \rangle = \left \langle u, \int_{\sigma (A)} t\ dE(t)\ u \right \rangle = \int_{\sigma (A)} t\ d\mu_u(t).$$ Here $\mu_u (S) : = \left \langle u, E(S)\ u \right \rangle,$ for any Borel measurable subset $S \subseteq \sigma (A).$ Clearly $\mu_u$ is a probability measure.

Comment: Now since $f$ is convex by integral version of Jensen's inequality we have $$\begin{align*} f \left (\left \langle u, Au \right \rangle \right ) & = f \left (\int_{\sigma (A)} t\ d\mu_u(t) \right ) \\ & \leq \int_{\sigma (A)} f(t)\ d\mu_u(t)\ \ (\text {by Jensen's inequality}) \\ & = \left \langle u, \int_{\sigma (A)} f(t)\ dE(t)\ u \right \rangle \\ & = \left \langle u, f(A)\ u \right \rangle\ \ (\text {by continuous functional calculus}) \end{align*}$$ This is what I did using spectral theorem for self-adjoint operators.

Comment: @MaoWao could you please have a look at my above comments and check whether it holds good or not?

Comment: @AntonioClaire Yes, that's another way to prove it. For the affine supporting functions have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative. Also, functional calculus is order preserving, i.e., $f\leq g$ implies $f(A)\leq g(A)$. You can see this directly from the integral representation you used in your comments.